# Transferring content from wordpress page to post

Tags: wordpress

what's the best way for me to copy content from my wordpress pages into a post?

I'm not an SEO nor IT expert, but I do know a little about duplicate content, URLs, slugs and stuff like that, but not enough to know how best to convert in 7 of my pages into posts.

I've thought of 
1) copying the html from the pages into posts and putting a rel=canonical in the pages to the corresponding posts (based on my understanding, my first choice)
2) Use a page to post wordpress plugin (not my first choice - afraid the plugin will break things)

Any help? Thank you!

Comment: if you want to convert pages in to wp posts you can do by changing its post_type from page to post. by doing code in functions.php and manually from DB.

Comment: or use the plugin "post type switcher" which does it for you - that way you can do it in bulk or in singular edit page

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried '[Post Type Switcher](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-type-switcher/)' plugin? I've used it and it worked without issues.